# How can i route user query from one agent to other agents in api.ai dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Iam trying to built multiple agents within api ai.i have devloped three agents  and i want that agent a gets user queries and forward it to the other agents how can agent forward user queries to other agent and can get response from those two agent and show to the user

Comment: Can't use Google Translate to decipher your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agents cannot directly route queries between themselves. You could take a look at the [query](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query) API from Dialogflow.  In your fulfillment you can take the user request and send a query to the other agent, then return that response back to the user.

Comment: thanks for your response i think i understand it, but still having some difficulties as i am new in this platform and there is not any good resource to learn more about it. could you please help me with some sample example

Comment: A good place to start may be looking at some of the [client-side samples for Dialoglfow](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2)